# Getting 2 .php pages in url

Tags: php

I have never seen anything like this before and I did a search and couldn't find anything about it.

I created a site map for my site and I noticed quite a few url's were like

```
url.com/page1.php/page.php
url.com/page1.php/page1.php
url.com/page1.php/page2.php
```

Any idea of why that would be doing that? I checked all my code but I don't see anything out of the ordinary but again, I have no clue why it would do that so I am not sure what to look for.

Comment: where is this URL appearing? more info required

Comment: It would be hard for us to know, most of our crystal balls are out for cleaning or repair.

Comment: What did you use to generate your sitemap, how does your links look like?

Comment: Most likely you have `anchor` tags with the `href` tag incorrect?

Comment: Not sure why I got a -2 for asking a question. But anyhow, I created my site map using the site map maker and that is when I noticed the duplicate .php files. Like I said, I have never seen that before and didn't know if anyone else has experienced that.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `header()` method that is build in PHP. It allows you to redirect the user to specific URL.

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
```